# Inserting data into a Genexus transaction grid

Tags: genexus

I have a multi-level transaction, so I have set up a free style grid which in turn contains a grid. I would need a button or procedure of some kind within the free style grid that would allow me to code data into the innermost grid.

Note that the problem occurs even with only one level, I cannot insert data "from code" into the grid of a transaction.

I can do this in a normal webpanel thanks to the grid.load event but this is not present in the transaction grids.

Is there a way to solve this problem and "programmatically" enter data into a grid without having to enter it by hand?

I'm working with genexus 16u9 and wwp 13.15, but it is a problem present in all versions